# What is the Catholic Church's Official Stance on ISIS?

Tags: catholicism, islam, pope-francis

What is the Catholic Church's Official Stance on ISIS?

Has Pope Francis actively encouraged the world's most powerful militaries to remove ISIS from the battlefield?

Or has he ever said anything like encouraging the world to "turn the other cheek"?

Comment: Keep in mind that Pope Francis' comments may or may not fully reflect "the Catholic Church's official stance", even where it has one.

Comment: Is there any reason to think the Catholic church has an official stance on ISIS? What would an official stance mean? How would it come about?

Comment: @Matt Gutting: Um. No. When the Pope speaks, he speaks on behalf of the Catholic Church.

Comment: @Flimzy: When the President speaks, he speaks on behalf of the United States. It is official. Likewise, when the Pope speaks, he speaks on behalf of the Catholic Church.

Comment: @JimG.: No, that's simply not true. There are times when the President speaks on behalf of the united states, but in almost all cases, for something to be "official", it must be ratified by the US Congress. When the President speaks, it is almost always as himself, expressing his own opinions. The only exceptions are in official acts, such as signing a bill, or an executive order. Likewise, the Pope rarely speaks "officially" (ex-cathedra).

Comment: When the Pope speaks, he can be speaking officially, on behalf of the Church and propounding doctrine; or he can give opinions to be seriously considered by all Catholics; or he can say things that are merely his own opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is the Catholic Church's Official Stance on ISIS?**
If you go by the utterances of the current Pope, there does not appear to be a coherent policy and the "official stance" appears to vary if the Pope is seen to be a credible spokesman for the Catholic Church. (See examples below). I have not seen an encyclical nor a Papal Bull of late enunciating a policy.  If one comes out, this answer will need to be updated.

**Has Pope Francis actively encouraged the world's most powerful militaries to remove ISIS from the battlefield?**
No.  He's not much of a militant pope, [unlike Pope Urban II](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/pope-urban-ii-orders-first-crusade)

Here is what the Pope has offered up to the media.

[The Pope Condemns ISIS.](http://americamagazine.org/issue/pope-francis-condemns-isis)  (2014)

> Thousands of people, including many Christians, driven from their
>   homes in a brutal manner; children dying of thirst and hunger in their
>   flight; women kidnapped; people massacred; violence of every
>   kind”—Pope Francis was clear in his condemnation of the actions of the
>   militants of the Islamic State in Iraq and Syria in his remarks on
>   Aug. 10: “All this greatly offends God and humanity. Hatred is not to
>   be carried in the name of God. War is not to be waged in the name of
>   God.” In a letter to U.N. General Secretary Ban Ki-moon on Aug. 9,
>   Pope Francis appealed to the international community “to take action
>   to end the humanitarian tragedy now underway.” He added, “The violent
>   attacks that are sweeping across Northern Iraq cannot but awaken the
>   consciences of all men and women of goodwill to concrete acts of
>   solidarity by protecting those affected or threatened by violence and
>   assuring the necessary and urgent assistance for the many displaced
>   people as well as their safe return to their cities and their homes.”

[The Pope is an apologist for ISIS](http://religionnews.com/2016/05/17/pope-francis-on-isis-the-gospel-sex-abuse-money-and-much-more/)

> “Today, I don’t think that there is a fear of Islam as such but of
>   ISIS and its war of conquest, which is partly drawn from Islam. It is
>   true that the idea of conquest is inherent in the soul of Islam.
>   However, it is also possible to interpret the objective in Matthew’s
>   Gospel, where Jesus sends his disciples to all nations, in terms of
>   the same idea of conquest.
>
> “In the face of Islamic terrorism, it would therefore be better to
>   question ourselves about the way an overly Western model of democracy
>   has been exported to countries such as Iraq, where a strong government
>   previously existed. Or in Libya, where a tribal structure exists. We
>   cannot advance without taking these cultures into account.”

[The Pope is mildly deluded](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/pope-francis-top-adviser-says-8037093).(2016)

> He said: "We have a mission to convert all non-Christian religions’
>   people [except] Judaism."  He added: "It is very clear that we can
>   speak about three Abrahamic religions but we cannot deny that the view
>   of Abraham in Jewish and the Christian tradition and the Islamic
>   tradition is not the same.

In a similar utterance, he opines that "this is not a religious war" to which ISIS responded "[yes, it is a religious war](http://dailycaller.com/2016/08/02/isis-tells-pope-this-is-a-religious-war/)."

[He refuses to confront the truth of ISIS](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3709420/Pope-Francis-shares-pain-horror-absurd-violence-condemns-forms-hatred-following-ISIS-murder-French-Catholic-priest.html). (2016)

> The Pontiff condemned *'every form of hatred'* and offered his prayers
>   to those involved.  Vatican spokesman Jesuit Father Federico Lombardi
>   issued a statement on the Pope's behalf after two ISIS knifemen
>   stormed a church in Normandy this morning.  He added that the Pope was
>   particularly appalled by the 'barbaric killing' because it happened in
>   a sacred place.  He went on to describe the attack as another act of
>   'absurd violence'.

This last one is the most difficult to assess given his position.  ISIS "soldiers" attack one of his priests, but ISIS' hatred of Christians isn't the topic of the Pope's remarks, but the vague "every form of hatred" gets condemnation.  A change from 2014, when he appealed to the UN for help ... or something.

Policy derived by analysis: the Pope (and by association, the Catholic Church) hopes that someone will deal with ISIS as he wrings his hands and the Church prays for the conversion of ISIS and its followers.  That last bit is at least consistent with Lumen Gentium, which was an official utterance of the church after Vatican II.

That is the only "policy" I can arrive at when examining the conflicting utterances offered up by the head of the Catholic Church.